# gvfs works in Krusader, with an Android phone, but "can't write into ..." when trying to copy a file into it

Tags: linux, arch-linux, android, gvfs

I use Krusader to access my Android phone and copy files to it. The path is this

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=<my_phone123>/
```

Firstly, it won't display the content of that path, even though it's been mounted, unless I first access via Thunar. Only after that Krusader will display the content of a phone and its SD card.

Secondly,when I'm attempting to copy a file, it'll throw an error "couldn't write into ... /downloads/123.txt"

How to fix all that?

Answer (score 0):

Either gvfs isn't starting, or it's starting and then exiting or crashing.

Crashed processes should be logged to /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog or wherever systemd does that these days.

The [gvfs debugging documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/debugging) also describes a GVFS_DEBUG environment variable, and ways to restart gvfs during a desktop session and capture its output. This might be the most helpful.

It can help to strace it to determine which system call it's failing in and with what error, eg. missing file, lack of permission. Possibly use `strace -f` to also follow child processes forked while stracing. It's a ton of output to dig through, though errors are usually close to the end.

gvfs is a DBus service. On it's [architecture diagram](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/ch01.html#gvfs-overview), the path from libgio and its plugins (gvfs module / dbus) to the "gvfs module", and in fact everything in that bottom block, is over DBus:

[image]

You can monitor all DBus requests, responses and events on your system. gvfsd runs in your session bus, so you can run something like this before those debugging commands from the debugging documentation:

```
dbus-monitor --session 2>&1 | tee dbus-log.txt
```

There's also a `dbus-monitor --system` to view gvfs <-> udisks2 communication and such.

I hope you fix this. Please report how it goes. I've done some gvfs-related development recently, so I should be able to help much more once I can look at some logs.