# GVFS not supporting schemes other than file:///

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, xfce, thunar, gvfs

This is what I believe to be the root of a much larger problem with my install of GVFS. I'm running XFCE4 on Linux Mint 20.04, and from *day 1* have not been able to use GVFS functions in any file manager. I can't use trash, I can't access SFTP servers or anything that requires GVFS. Trying to open the trash on Thunar displays

> **Failed to open 'trash:///'** Operation not supported.

Similar messages appear on other file managers, usually with 'Operation not supported.'

When going into preferences, Thunar displays

> It looks like **gvfs** is not available

Upon actually digging in the Thunar source code, I found that what it is actually doing here is testing the [get_supported_uri_schemes](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GVfs.html#g-vfs-get-supported-uri-schemes) function for common things like `trash` and `sftp`, and saying 'gvfs is not available' if those don't show as supported. I tested this myself with the below code snippet (taken from the Thunar source), and the only supported scheme returned by the function is `file`. I can confirm this by typing paths into the Thunar top-bar; it complains when anything except `file:///` is entered.

```
const gchar * const *supported_schemes;
gboolean             supported = FALSE;
guint                n;
GVfs                *gvfs;

gvfs = g_vfs_get_default ();
supported_schemes = g_vfs_get_supported_uri_schemes (gvfs);

if (supported_schemes == NULL)
    return FALSE;

for (n = 0; !supported && supported_schemes[n] != NULL; ++n)
    if (g_strcmp0 (supported_schemes[n], "trash") == 0)
    supported = TRUE;

return supported;
```

Upon even further digging into [old forum posts](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-permanently-get-rid-of-this-horrible-gvfs-metadata-beast-4175530495/), it seems that on a working machine, the gvfs daemon is supposed to be started automatically by Nautilus, Thunar or any other file manager that requests it (not sure how that works). This doesn't happen on my machine, for a reason I've yet to determine. I am able to start the service manually using
`systemctl --user start gvfs-daemon`, but this process running doesn't change the output of `get_supported_uri_schemes`.

**Things I've Tried (that didn't work)**

1. Reinstalling glib, gvfs (and every listed dependency for gvfs package)
2. Installing gvfs-backends, gvfs-common etc.
3. Adding `exec dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session xfce4-session` to my `.xinitrc` (as per [this old post](https://forums.funtoo.org/topic/4829-thunar-doesnt-recognise-gvfs-solved/))
4. Manually starting gvfs-daemon using `systemctl`
5. Running the entire session as root (`startx` from root terminal), the same problem there

Can anyone point me in the vague direction of what might be wrong with gvfs here? Why doesn't it register as supporting anything other than `file:///`? Why doesn't the daemon start automatically with the file managers?

I appreciate any help anyone can render here, please comment if more information is required.

Comment: Please see the detailed gvfs debugging info I posted on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639996/6525
and report back with some results.

Comment: @damjan The log is completely empty, even after trying `gio open trash:///` in another shell while the daemon is running - and that returning `Operation not supported.`

Comment: @damjan The dbus-log seems to indicate that the gvfs daemon has started (after `systemctl --user start gvfs-daemon`), but I can find no evidence that Thunar is communicating with it. Here is the log: https://pastebin.com/E0nNLe4W